# Find all leaf node records using hierarchyid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hierarchyid

How would I go about querying for only records that are "only leaf nodes"
(ie. no children)?

I have tried a query like this:

```
select *
from TableA tt
where tt.HierarchyId.GetDescendant(null, null) not in 
(
    Select  t.HierarchyId
    from TableA t
)
```

But this still seemed to return some nodes that had children.

I am using the built-in hierarchyid data type (part of ms sqlserver)

Comment: I new I had seen this query before and I have found a scenario where it fails. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8562690/569436). BTW, The new answer I have provided is pretty much the same as the answer by @AaronBertrand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT A.HieracrchyId, A.HierarchyId.ToString()
  FROM dbo.TableA AS A 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TableA AS B
  ON A.HierarchyId = B.HierarchyId.GetAncestor(1)
  WHERE B.HierarchyId IS NULL;
```